# Child element is not being added to parent (parent.appendChild)

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty sure I'm going to kick myself hard (very hard) when I see an answer to this but when I do `console.log(markerDiv)` the console just outputs the img element. What am I doing wrong?

Edited as answers suggest:

```
var dynamic = document.createElement("img");
dynamic.src = "images/dynamic.png";
dynamic.setAttribute("id", "img-" + markerData[data].registration);
var markerDiv = document.createElement("div");
markerDiv.appendChild(dynamic);

console.log(markerDiv);
```

Result of console.log:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) returns a reference to the child, not the parent, so you can't chain it like that:

```
var markerDiv = document.createElement("div").appendChild(dynamic);
// markerDiv === dynamic
```

Break the chain, and it'll work:

```
var markerDiv = document.createElement("div");
markerDiv.appendChild(dynamic);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this didn't appear to solve my problem. I've edited the question.

Comment: @JoelKidd your new code works for me (or would, if `markerData[data].registration` was defined)

Comment: Yes it does for me too in a fresh document. How odd... maybe it's cached or something. I'll select as best answer anyway as this code is what I originally asked for and does work in a fresh document.

Answer (score 2):

You are not appending your newly created div to the DOM. `Node.appendChild` returns the newly created node(`HTMLImageElement` in your case).

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(dynamic);
document.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this didn't appear to solve my problem. I've edited the question.